# How to test routes using regEx in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

I have some routes in my Node Js single plage application which update without page load. I wanna test some routes using regEx to get a perfect match of the route.

I have `/index`, `/contact`, `/products` in switch statement.

```
    switch(window.location.pathname)
        case '/index':
            break;
         case '/contact':
            break;
         case '/products':
            break;
    default:
            //Returning error page if none of pathname met
             break;
```

How can I make it possible for a user to visit `/products/iphone` or `/products/:brandName/:productId` and be able to get the values of *:brandName* and *:productId* in JavaScript using regEx in vanilla JavaScript

Comment: you won't be able to use a regex if you're using switch .... well, you can, but it makes for poor code

Comment: Is there other ways of solving the problem I have without regEx!? How if I use if...else condition!?

Comment: there's ways to do it with and without regex, you just have to try

Comment: Can you please tell me how!?

Comment: Maybe you already searched "matching any ending with regex", came across something like using "/products/[a-zA-Z]*", but have a more specific question thereafter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this - since the "parts" of the pathname are always separated by `/` there's no need for the complexity of a `regex` - a simple `.split` will do just fine

```
// the leading , is NOT a typo
const [, root, ...rest] = location.pathname.split('/');

switch (root)
case '/index':
    break;
case '/contact':
    break;
case '/products': {
        const [brandName, productId, ...more] = rest;
        // brandName and productId will be the first two parts of the path after /products
    }
    break;
default:
    //Returning error page if none of pathname met
    break;
```